# How can you locate the default style for a widget (i.e. AppCompatEditText)

Tags: android, styles, themes

> ***UPDATE:** As pointed out in the comments, 'Widget.AppCompat.EditText' is the correct parent style for an AppCompatEditText subclass.  In my case, the real issue was I had forgotten to assign a value to our control's default style attribute in our theme, so our control wasn't getting any style to use as a default.*
>
> *However, this question still could use an answer as to how one properly identifies which style to use as a parent when defining your own default styles when subclassing the standard controls. As such, I've also renamed its title.*
>
> *As such, I'm leaving this open in hopes someone can answer that question since it will help any who wish to do something similar.*

We're trying to define a common look-and-feel for all AppCompatEditText controls used throughout the app.  As such, rather than having to manually apply the 'style' attribute on each usage, we're instead trying to replace the default style with our own.

Replacing the default style is actually the easy part.  What isn't is knowing what the parent style for our style should be set to so we still have all aspects of the original style which we haven't explicitly overwritten with those in ours.

Digging in the source code for AppCompatEditText, it shows the default style to be stored in `R.attr.editTextStyle` but I'm not sure where now to look to see what value is stored in it.

Experimenting too didn't get us anywhere.  No matter what we have tried so far, we lose the default appearance completely.  No underline, no background, no padding, nothing. Just the values we've set, which means it's not picking up the parent style.

We've tried the following without success...

```
<style name="ZinEditText" parent="android:Widget.EditText">
    <item name="zinTypeface">light</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/defaultTextSize</item>
    <item name="android:lineSpacingMultiplier">@dimen/defaultLineSpacing</item>
</style>

<style name="ZinEditText" parent="Widget.AppCompat.EditText">
    <item name="zinTypeface">light</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/defaultTextSize</item>
    <item name="android:lineSpacingMultiplier">@dimen/defaultLineSpacing</item>
</style>

<style name="ZinEditText" parent="Base.V7.Widget.AppCompat.EditText">
    <item name="zinTypeface">light</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/defaultTextSize</item>
    <item name="android:lineSpacingMultiplier">@dimen/defaultLineSpacing</item>
</style>

<style name="ZinEditText" parent="Widget.Holo.EditText">
    <item name="zinTypeface">light</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/defaultTextSize</item>
    <item name="android:lineSpacingMultiplier">@dimen/defaultLineSpacing</item>
</style>
```

As I said, none of the above seemed to work.

So how does one find the actual parent style to use?

Comment: The default is [`Widget.AppCompat.EditText`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/master/v7/appcompat/res/values/themes_base.xml#223). How are you setting the style?

Comment: @#$$!  I forgot to assign our style to our style attribute.  You're right.  The style was working all along.

Comment: Post yours as an answer, including the piece that I left out and I'll mark yours as the accepted one.  Better than answering this myself or leaving it open.  Plus you get points.

Comment: We've all been there. :-) This was just a simple oversight. If you wanna call it a freebie, I don't mind if you just wanna delete this. Up to you. Glad you got it working.

Comment: Actually, even better, since technically my question was about how to know what the default style was, even though that wasn't the root of my actual problem, that question still could use an answer. You knew right away what it was.  Mind writing up how you looked that up so others working on other components would know where to go too?  For instance, what about Buttons, Radio Buttons, and Checkboxes?  Basically any of the standard controls.

Comment: Sure, I can do that. I'm heading into a meeting shortly, though, so I won't be able to get to it for a bit.

Comment: Lemme know if that's not clear, or if there's anything you'd like further explanation for. I've never really spelled out a process for this. It's usually just me bouncing around the various source directories.

Comment: Dude, that was perfect!

Comment: Excellent. Glad I could help. Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To address the immediate issue, the default style for an `AppCompatEditText` is `Widget.AppCompat.EditText`. The second example you've shown is the correct one:

```
<style name="ZinEditText" parent="Widget.AppCompat.EditText">
    ...
```

This needs to be set as the `editTextStyle` in your app theme.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="editTextStyle">@style/ZinEditText</item>
    ...
```

---

Finding these default styles and attributes is not well documented anywhere officially, as far as I'm aware. The official documentation for [Styles and Themes](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html#Attributes) simply directs one to the various `R.attr` pages for the framework and support packages, to "discover" what's available. However, a generally reliable way to find this for most `View`s that allow a default style is to inspect the source code.

A `View` subclass will often implement at least three constructors: one that takes only a `Context`; one that takes a `Context` and an `AttributeSet`; and one that takes a `Context`, an `AttributeSet`, and an `int` for `defStyleAttr`, a *default style attribute*. This attribute is what we're looking for. It will usually have a sensible name, like `editTextStyle`, `textViewStyle`, `checkboxStyle`, etc. If you already know the name, you can skip checking the `View` class for it.

In `View`s that chain their constructors, this attribute will be normally be in the call to the three-parameter constructor from the two-parameter one. In [`AppCompatEditText`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/master/v7/appcompat/src/android/support/v7/widget/AppCompatEditText.java), we can see that the name of this attribute is `editTextStyle`.

```
public AppCompatEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, R.attr.editTextStyle);
}
```

After we've got the name for the attribute, we then head to the `res/values/` directory for the platform or support package the `View` is in. The default value will be in the relevant `themes*.xml` file for your app's parent theme.

For the platform themes, there is a base [`themes.xml`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/res/res/values/themes.xml), and a [few others](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/res/res/values/) for specific theme versions, such as Holo and Material.

For support library `View`s, these theme files will be under the package-specific `res/values/` directory, and the default attribute value may be in `themes.xml` or `themes_base.xml`.

In v7 appcompat, our app's exact parent theme is likely in [`v7/appcompat/res/values/themes.xml`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/master/v7/appcompat/res/values/themes.xml), though most of the themes there are just direct aliases for base themes; i.e., they don't override any of their parents' attribute values. The default for `AppCompatEditText` is actually in [`v7/appcompat/res/values/themes_base.xml`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/master/v7/appcompat/res/values/themes_base.xml). There are separate entries for different themes - the regular, and the light - but they are both the same.

```
<item name="editTextStyle">@style/Widget.AppCompat.EditText</item>
```

This is enough to determine which style to use as our parent, but should we want to check out the style specifics, we can then refer to [`v7/appcompat/res/values/styles.xml`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/master/v7/appcompat/res/values/styles.xml), where we find that style's parent:

```
<style name="Widget.AppCompat.EditText" parent="Base.Widget.AppCompat.EditText"/>
```

which leads us to [`v7/appcompat/res/values/styles_base.xml`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/master/v7/appcompat/res/values/styles_base.xml):

```
<style name="Base.Widget.AppCompat.EditText" parent="Base.V7.Widget.AppCompat.EditText" />

<style name="Base.V7.Widget.AppCompat.EditText" parent="android:Widget.EditText">
    <item name="android:background">?attr/editTextBackground</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">?attr/editTextColor</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">?android:attr/textAppearanceMediumInverse</item>
</style>
```